# .htaccess, как сократить url?

Tags: .htaccess

Есть такая структура сайта:

```
site
  client
    loginpage
      index.php
    mainpage
      index.php
    blogpage
      index.php
  server
    login.php
    savesession.php
    // Всякие другие скрипты
```

При запуске сервера рабочей директорией выбрана `site`. Сделано это затем, чтобы из `index.php` можно было ссылаться  на скрипты из папки server.  Если выбрать client, то никак не получится ссылаться на эти скрипты (вроде бы, могу ошибаться вполне, просьба поправить).
Все нормально работает, уже написано, но не нравится url.
То есть для страницы логина url будет таким: `http://site/client/login`.
Как можно подправить .htaccess, чтобы страницы были такими: `http://site/login`, то есть попросту без отображения папки `client`?
К тому же очень интересует, будет ли это чисто визуальный эффект или придется все пути в скриптах переписывать?

Comment: `RewriteRule` - меняет запрос, но не меняет URL. Но если указать редиррект - поменяется и URL. Комбинируйте по усмотрению. В скриптах придется переписывать **относительные** пути, т.к. они собираются от URL

Comment: @DNS ни разу не работал с htaccess. Из гугления и разных примеров не смог написать RewriteRule правильно.

Comment: @DNS легче будет просто изменить структуру проекта и ссылки на страницах.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать RewritwRule в .htaccess, то будет как-то так (не проверял!)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^login.php$ client/login/index.php [L]
```

Это при условии, что понял  я вас правильно и client это папка, а не переменная и у каждого клиента своя.
Соответственно url для логина у клиента будет выглядеть http://site.url/login.php и его перенаправит на http://site.url/client/login/index.php

Comment: Ну уже поздно, я переделал структуру проекта, но спасибо, буду знать.

Comment: Не думаю, что верно поняли... client - это просто папка для готовых страниц по сути. Клиентов никаких нет)

Comment: Ну и я не могу запустить этот пример, но мне не нужен редирект. Мне нужно, чтобы в адресной строке была красивая ссылка.